# hiqpdf html conversion issue

Tags: c#, html, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, hiqpdf

I am using HiQPdf to convert and combine a list of html page into one pdf document.
this is how i'm doing this:

```
public class HtmlToPdfEditor
{
    private string _firstPage;
    private string _secondPage;
    //private const string _HiQPdfSerialNumber = "";
    private PdfDocument _document;
    public HtmlToPdfEditor(string firstPage, string secondPage)
    {
        _firstPage = firstPage;
        _secondPage=secondPage;
    }

    public void ConvertAll(string outputPath) 
    {
         HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        _document = new PdfDocument();
        //_document.SerialNumber = _HiQPdfSerialNumber;
        string firstPageDoc = GetDocument(_firstPage, "firstPage.pdf");
        string secondPageDoc = GetDocument(_secondPage, "secondtPage.pdf");

        this.JoinDocument(PdfFromFile(firstPageDoc));
        this.JoinDocument(PdfFromFile(secondPageDoc));
        _document.WriteToFile(outputPath);
        _document.Close();
        _document = null;
    }

    private PdfDocument PdfFromFile(string path)
    {
        return PdfDocument.FromFile(path);
    }


    private int JoinDocument(PdfDocument document)
    {
        var nbPages = _document.Pages.Count;
        _document.AddDocument(document);
        document.Close();
        return nbPages;
    }

    private string GetDocument(string content, string outputFile)
    {
       var baseUrl = "";
       var htmlToPdfConverter = GetPdfExporter();
       htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToFile(content, baseUrl, outputFile);
       return outputFile;
    }

    public HtmlToPdf GetPdfExporter()
    {
        HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        //htmlToPdfConverter.SerialNumber = _HiQPdfSerialNumber;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins = new PdfMargins(2);
        htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlLoadedTimeout = 60;
        htmlToPdfConverter.TriggerMode = ConversionTriggerMode.WaitTime; //Time to load the html
        htmlToPdfConverter.WaitBeforeConvert = 1;
        return htmlToPdfConverter;

    }
}
```

The issue here is that in the resulting document the page converted from html are displayed as empty pages, only google chrome display them correctly , in firefox these pages continue indefinitely in the loading state.

Notice that if I convert the Html to a PdfDocument instead of storing it to a file and then joining it. The resulting document is perfectly readable but unfortunately I can't use this method.

Any help will be much apreciated!! thx!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct, the PDF documents you add to a main document must remain opened until you close the main document.

If the PDF documents you merge are produced from HTML there is actually an easier way to merge the HTML documents in a PDF following the approach from [Convert Many HTML to PDF](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertManyHtmlToPdf.aspx) example.

```
// create an empty PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// add a page to document
PdfPage page1 = document.AddPage(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfDocumentMargins(5), 
        PdfPageOrientation.Portrait);

try
{
    // set the document header and footer before 
    // adding any objects to document
    SetHeader(document);
    SetFooter(document);

    // layout the HTML from URL 1
    PdfHtml html1 = new PdfHtml(textBoxUrl1.Text);
    PdfLayoutInfo html1LayoutInfo = page1.Layout(html1);

    // determine the PDF page where to add URL 2
    PdfPage page2 = null;
    System.Drawing.PointF location2 = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
    if (checkBoxNewPage.Checked)
    {
        // URL 2 is laid out on a new page with the selected orientation
        page2 = document.AddPage(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfDocumentMargins(5), 
            GetSelectedPageOrientation());
        location2 = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        // URL 2 is laid out immediately after URL 1 and html1LayoutInfo
        // gives the location where the URL 1 layout finished
        page2 = document.Pages[html1LayoutInfo.LastPageIndex];
        location2 = new System.Drawing.PointF(html1LayoutInfo.LastPageRectangle.X, 
            html1LayoutInfo.LastPageRectangle.Bottom);
    }

    // layout the HTML from URL 2
    PdfHtml html2 = new PdfHtml(location2.X, location2.Y, textBoxUrl2.Text);
    page2.Layout(html2);

    // write the PDF document to a memory buffer
    byte[] pdfBuffer = document.WriteToMemory();

    // inform the browser about the binary data format
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    // let the browser know how to open the PDF document
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                String.Format("attachment; filename=LayoutMultipleHtml.pdf;
                        size={0}",
                pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

    // call End() method of HTTP response 
    // to stop ASP.NET page processing
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
finally
{
    document.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved this issue by ensuring that all pdf documents to be merged are closed after closing the final document. In other words the method JoinDocument will no longer call document.Close(). I'll call it later after closing the final document (_document).